# Visual Studio Python Debugger closes right after run

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I have a python project. I click on a .py file and hit run with out debugger and the console comes up and the program runs. if I use run with debugger the console flashes and close. there are words on it. but it closes to fast for me to read. I have Set everything in tools I think I can. I have python debugger interactive.

import sys class Test(): 
def **init**(self): 
var = raw_input("Hit Enter") 
t = 'test' 
print t 
stepB = raw_input("Hit Enter") 
a = Test()

place brake pint at t = 'test'

Comment: Can you give an example of the code that is doing this, or at least describe what the program does?

Comment: import sys

class Test():

    def __init__(self):
        var = raw_input("Hit Enter")
        t = 'test'
        print t
        stepB = raw_input("Hit Enter")

a = Test()

Comment: I place a brake point on t='test' If I run this with out debuging it wroks fine. with dubuging the console flashe and closes

Comment: Please edit the code in to the original question.